# Array sorting and reversing behaviour

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I've found that when using the sort() function, I can use it like so:

```
sort($myArray);
```

and `$myArray` is sorted. But when I use array_reverse like this:

```
array_reverse($myArray);
```

The array is not reversed. To get it to work I have to do this:

```
$myArray = array_reverse($myArray);
```

And people have posted problems before wondering why their array_reverse wasn't working and it was because of this.

I was wondering, why do these two functions behave differently (does it have to do with passing by reference), and wouldn't php try to standardize?

Comment: Why do they behave differently? Only the original development team can answer that! Whay haven't they been standardised since? Backward Compatibility! How do you know they behave differently? You read the PHP documentation for the functions!

Comment: Don't even get me started on *needle, haystack* order. Sheesh! :-) But `rsort()` which is the inverse of `sort()` works like you think it would. Because sorting and reversing are really two different things.

Comment: You are correct, PHP has a standardization issue.

Comment: Not opinion based, but got one good answer anyways

Comment: If you think only PHP is this inconsistent, consider the following javascript `0 > null
false
0 >= null
true
0 == null
false
0 <= null
true
0 < null
false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They behave differently because in `sort` the `$myArray` variable is passed by reference, meaning the variable itself is operated on whereas in `array_reverse()` the variable is not passed by reference. You could simulate this behavior by using `array_reverse(&$myArray)` Although, please note that as of PHP 5.3.0 call-time pass by reference was deprecated and it was completely removed in PHP 5.4.0

As for the why, I have no idea. Some one in their infinite wisdom decided that when you sort you must want to sort the actual array but when you reverse you must want to save it to a new array variable.

Read more about passing by reference here: http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.references.pass.php

There are plenty of little oddities like that in PHP. That's why I keep the PHP docs bookmarked for quick reference in just these situations :)

Comment: Because sorting and reversing are two different things.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - Nobody suggested that they performed the same function, just that it's an inconsistent way to have array functions operate.

Comment: Yeah...I know. I have watched the dev team argue for years over these things.

Comment: I suppose all languages have their little inconsistencies that you have to love to hate. Or hate to love. Or something...

Comment: I see what you did there.